# Angular, How to set validation for either of two field should validate in reaction form approach

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, angular4-forms

I'm trying to set user form validation, user must enter either of two fields, mobile or email fields

Add Guest reaction form Html:

```
<form class="new_guest" id="new_guest" [formGroup]="addGuestForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input placeholder="Enter guest name" class="add-guests form-control ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" formControlName="name"
                    id="guest_name" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input placeholder="Enter guest email" class="add-guests form-control ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" formControlName="email"
                    id="guest_email" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input placeholder="Mobile Number, If any" class="add-guests form-control ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" formControlName="mobile"
                    id="guest_mobile" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" id="add_guest" value="ADD GUEST" [disabled]="!addGuestForm.valid">
        </form
```

AddGuest init:

```
this.addGuestForm = new FormGroup({
  'name': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  'email': new FormControl(null, Validators.email),
  'mobile': new FormControl(null)
})
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can subscribe to the form's [`valueChanges`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) and validate it there

Comment: You can also ask to google :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use form builder and provide customized validation for example:

```
this.addGuestForm = this.formBuilder.group({
'name': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  'email': '',
  'mobile': ''
}, {
      validator: (formControl) => {
        var emailCtrl = formControl.controls.email;
        var mobileCtrl = formControl.controls.mobile;


        if (emailCtrl != undefined && mobileCtrl != undefined)
             if(!(emailCtrl.value.length || mobileCtrl.value.length ))
                    return {invalid: true};
}
});
```

additionally you can also check for regex for email field 
define a variable regexPattern for email pattern check and use below in the custom validator if condition

```
regexPattern.test(emailCtrl.value)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my solution is a writing a custom validator:

```
export function oneOfControlRequired(...controls: AbstractControl[]): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        for (const aControl of controls) {
          if (!Validators.required(aControl)) {
            return null;
          }
        }
        return { oneOfRequired: true };
     };
}
```

and you could use like that:

```
this.addGuestForm.setValidators([
  oneOfControlRequired(
      this.addGuestForm.get('email'),
      this.addGuestForm.get('mobile'),
  )
]);
```

maybe you want to slightly modify the `oneOfControlRequired` function to take `controlNames: string[]` as input param not `AbstractControl[]`

you can check the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-one-of-required-validator?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly changed the answer of @pogiaron So you can set the error key returned.

```
static oneControlRequired(errorKey: string, ...controls: AbstractControl[]) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        for (const aControl of controls) {
          if (!Validators.required(aControl)) {
            return null;
          }
        }
        return { [errorKey]: true };
     };
}
```